# add IconButton component beside the every Material UI TableRow

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add an icon beside the material UI table row component.

that's like the hint icon in the below screenshot

this is what I made so far and it doesn't work correctly:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-james-9q53r0?file=/demo.tsx)

[image: yellow icon beside table row]

Answer (score 1):

I updated your sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-edison-6625rj?file=/demo.tsx
I removed position="relative" from Table element, cuz your absolute positioned child will follow the closest parent it can find in the DOM with position relative, and you don't want that in this case. If it cant find any parent with position='relative' it will fall to body.
Also i set the height of Box to 50px thats just to centre your icon, its basically the height of your row, you can play around with that.